# Formatting time to remove unnecessary 00's from the timer

Tags: java, string, string-formatting

I'm trying to clean up my timer for my application but im having difficulties getting it to do what I want.

Would anyone know how to format H:M:S and remove the 00's?

Example the time may start like this: 12:34:56 (hh:mm:ss)

But once the time reaches lets say 00:34:56, remove the remaining 00's,
I'm a bit worried about performance which is why I'm here to find the more efficient way to format the time as this will be called a lot.

Would `String.format("%02d:%02d", m, s).replaceAll("00:","");` be a wise choice?

Thanks.

Comment: I think the effort to remove the leading `00` might be more wasteful than just using the API as it is.  Not to mention, it leaves your time data presentation inconsistent, with smaller values having only 4 (2?) digits instead of 6.

Comment: `replaceAll("00:","")` is not a good choice, consider `11:00:21 => 11:21` gets a wrong time.

Comment: you can compare date with 01:00:00 then format according to result, `hh:mm:ss` or `mm:ss` .

Answer (score 2):

I assume you could be negligibly faster by just checking the first 2 characters:

```
if (timeString.charAt(0) == '0' && timeString.charAt(1) == '0')
   timeString = timeString.substring(3);
```

I don't necessarily think that's great code, but 2 character checks would probably be faster than a larger string search.  Not by much, though, so I doubt it's worth it.

(Made a fix based on the comment, changing `== '1'` to `== '0'` )

Comment: Apparently I can't edit a single character for you, but the `== '1'` should say `== '0'`

Comment: Fixed it in the answer. Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

Using a regular expression, you can delete **only** the first section  '00:' using (It's only for deleting the hour part in a HH:MM::SS time format)

```
String.format("%02d:%02d", m, s).replaceAll("^00:","");
```

*^ is a character to mark the beginning of a line*

Answer (score 1):

You have practically answered your own question.  Just turn your thoughts into code.

What you need:

> If the time is less than one hour, show only minutes and seconds;  else, show hours, minutes and seconds.

Your code should read like the spoken version:

```
if (hours < 1) {
    text = String.format("%02d:%02d", minutes, seconds);
} else {
    text = String.format("%02d:%02d:%02d", hours, minutes, seconds);
}
```

Simple, clean, fast, and easy for future programmers (including yourself, a year from now) to understand.